# C# selenium cant find input in form

Tags: c#, html, forms, selenium

I am trying to locate a button in a form... but it doesnt find it...
I have tryed using threading.sleep(5000); but it dont help.
I have tryed so many ways but nothing helped me it always says that it cant locate the button...
here is my code:

```
IWebElement startb2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form/*[@name='start']"));
```

here is the html code of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="php/PickFruits.php">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="התחל לקטוף" class="button_submit" style="margin-right:-97px;">
</form>
```

I don't want to use the value because it is in Hebrew... and I cant use it in the c# console... please help me guys.

Edit:

Now its find the location of the input but it doesnt click on it... code:

```
IWebElement startb = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@type='submit']"));
startb.Click();
```

Comment: try xpath = '//*[@type="submit"]'

Comment: it worked but it doesnt click on it :l code: IWebElement startb = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@type='submit']"));
                    startb.Click();

Comment: did it give you an error while clicking?

Comment: try adding some delay before you perform click operation.

Comment: I added but still nothing :l

Comment: the page on which you are trying to click have jQuery on it or not ?

Comment: there is this file in the head: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: but everything else is javascript

Comment: Ohhhh wait maybe because all this is in iframe? and not in the website himself? this is the iframe code: <iframe src="actives/PickFruits.php" class="active_iframe"></iframe>

Comment: Yes, most probably. Because if you want to execute some operation on an iframe, you have to first switch to that iframe.

Comment: ok and how do i do that? can you write for me the code with the iframe,the form,and the input with xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to an iframe, use the below code.

```
//To find the iframe
IWebElement Object = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='active_iframe']");
//To switch to and set focus to the iframe
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Object);
```

And then perform click  operation.

```
IWebElement startb = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@type='submit']"));
startb.Click();
```

Comment: what is the xpath to my iframe? I have no idea:l iframe code: <iframe src="actives/PickFruits.php" class="active_iframe"></iframe>

Comment: Added XPATH based on what you posted. Check now

Comment: but wait when I done with this Iframe how do I get back? I mean how i stop focus on that iframe and start looking on the all website?

Comment: driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent(); you can use this to return back to top most frame on your page